# How can I rename the radios I added to Banshee?

Tags: banshee, internet-radio

With Banshee 1.8 you can add radio stations to the dedicated panel. The 'Add a station' button gives the possibility to indicate the stream address, a name, a genre and so on.

However those informations seem to be given once and for all, as there is no 'Edit station' option in the contextual menu. So how can I modify the information associated to the saved stations, for example their name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are supposed to be able to right click on a station and edit it, but if you are using Banshee 1.8.0 or earlier you are out of luck, there is a bug, once you create a station you can not edit it, here is the [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=624734).

The problem is now fixed in the latest stable release 1.8.1 as of January 28, 2011, see the [release notes](http://banshee.fm/download/archives/1.8.1/).

I have updated Banshee to 1.8.1 and checked, you can now indeed, right click on a radio station entry and edit it.

Banshee 1.8.1 is currently going through the update process in 10.10 and should be provided as an update in the next couple of days.